TCP packet being sent is exceeding the MSS of a connection -- how is this possible?
I'm very new to networking/network driver design principles and would love some help and direction troubleshooting an odd behavior I'm seeing from a tcpdump captured within a device.
The logs are showing that the device (Linux-based) will occasionally send packets with a size exceeding the established MSS value. I am fairly certain the capture is reflective of what is being sent on the wire. This assumption is based on the fact that the peer does not acknowledge these MSS-violating packets, and that the device is indeed re-sending these dropped packets. The peer has no issue ack-ing correctly sized TCP packets, so I strongly believe this is an issue with the device.
I'm trying to narrow down the area of problem, but I'd like a clearer picture of the different circumstances in which this issue can be made possible. To my knowledge, tcpdump logs from a host would mean the packets I am seeing are captured in-between the kernel and NIC/hardware driver layer. My initial guess of where the problem lies would be in the kernel; this is based on my amateur assumption that the kernel/tcp-driver should be the one responsible for segmenting the data correctly before being sent to the NIC.
If that assumption is true, then would that mean the network interface hardware is the area of problem, and that these network devices have the processing capability to identify TCP-packets and pool them into a single packet?
If that assumption isn't true, then would that mean these network devices are typically designed to store connection-based information in order to properly segment the data received from the CPU?
Also I feel like I need to note that this problematic machine I am analyzing does indeed have an external switch between itself and the wire.
Thank you in advance for any insight someone is able to provide.

The MSS is a TCP option that may or may not be used. It is sent from the other side only in the SYN if it is used at all. If the other side does not use the MSS option, there is no limit on the segment size it will accept. Also, switches are transparent devices, and they do not fragment IP packets or segment TCP datagrams. TCP segments data into segments that are then encapsulated in IP packets, that are then wrapped in ethernet frames. Ethernet knows nothing of its payload, IP knows nothing of its payload, and TCP knows nothing of its payload. The layers are independent of each other.

@RonMaupin I guess it technically doesn't need to be used, but if the MSS is advertised in the TCP handshake, a properly implemented network stack is going to cap the outgoing segment size when transferring to the peer, right? The only purpose to selectively ignore the MSS I can think of is for network flooding/attacks. You're right that most basic switches don't handle fragmentation, but I found out the switch we use is some custom L3 switch with that capability. It's effectively the chip's NIC, which was interesting to discover.

Enterprise routers. e.g. Cisco, can intercept and change the MSS if configured to do so, even if not set, but it is an option that not every application uses. The side not using it does not care what segment size it receives.

Alright I think I found the answer:
It looks like how TCP frames are sent to the NIC depends on the settings/implementation. For Linux it looks like they have a performance option (TSO) to either do the TCP segmentation themselves before sending it to the lower-layers, or to instead just send a large chunk of data to the NIC and offload that TCP segmentation work to it.
I see that the ethernet interface on the device has TSO enabled, so it looks like the issue is within the external switch's software that isn't segmenting the packets correctly before being sent to the wire.
